# Can i host /install sharepoint in such case?

Tags: sharepoint, vmware-server, vmware-player

I have installed the windows XP on which i have the VMWare as virtual server. I want to install / Host the sharepoint in such scenario in VMWare . Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Why wouldn't it be possible?

Comment: No i have doubt about,WSS. Means WSS is the supporting services for MOSS2007 / sharepoint right? so is VMWare provides WSS as extension like in windows 2k3 ?

Comment: @Lalit VMWare only provides a virtualization platform. You use VMWare to host a fully fledged win2k3 installation on the machine in question.

Comment: I agree with you sir, but if VMWare on XP will that work. Means is that means VMWare is virtual 2k3 ?

Comment: @Lalit Yes, I can confirm that you can install windows 2003 server on a VWWare instance that runs on windows XP. I have done it many times, and also with sharepoint installed on the virtual win2k3 server.

Answer (score 0):

That is how I have mine set up, VMware. It is very possible, and very common.